# Dividing a Int and turning it to string

Tags: int

Im going crazy here.

I have a Integer with a value of 500. I need to divide it with 1000 and then send the value as a string.

Now i turn it to a float and it works fine if the value is like 2000/1000 then it gives me 2.0 but as soon as the value is lower then 1000 then it gives me 0.0 back. How come? What do i need to change?

More info:

I working with Jaspersoft ETL studio and language is JAVA.
Left side is a Integer in the middle i create a Variable for calculation and on the right side is the my final string.

[image]

Comment: More info needed: programming language, code used etc. please extend your question.

Comment: Sorry my bad, now more infos is added

Answer (score 1):

An integer is, by definition, a whole number and 500/1000 is 0.5 (not an integer).

How to solve your problem really depends on the language you're using. Using a float for the division is a good start. Then you should look at [casting types](https://www.google.com/search?q=casting%20types&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=casting%20types%20in%20java) in your language of choice (java example in link).

Answer (score 0):

When/how do you turn it into a float?

Look at this python example, and see if it helps you:

```
float(500/1000)
Out[2]: 0.0

float(500)/float(1000)
Out[3]: 0.5
```